# Replacing entire header-line in a fasta-file

Tags: python

I have a fasta-file, which is of the format:

">somename1
ATAGCATGCATCGACTAG
ACGCATCGTGAC"

">somename2
ACGTCAGCTAGCT
ACGTCAGCTGA"

and so forth.

I need to replace the headers (eg. >somename1), with another string.
I have made a dictionary of my fasta files and a list of the names, the headers should be replaced with.

```
Some pseudocode:
for fasta in fastas:
    file = open(fasta, "r")
    for line in file:
        if line.startwith(">"):
            *line.replace(new_header)*
```

The "*" indicates, where I'm not sure what to do.
The line.replace command doesnt seem to do anything.
Do i need to tell Python to write the file also?

Thanks!

Comment: post your complete code in which you have made dictionary

Comment: Yes, you need to also write to a file, a different file than you are reading from.

Comment: So I can't just replace the string in the same file? I have to write to an entire new file?
The files a quite huge, so it would be a massive job to write everything to a brand new file, just to replace a header.

Comment: Solved. I ended up using filesinput.input.